# Power management driver - suse vs centos

Tags: centos, power-management, opensuse

I have a hand-held PC and have installed CentOS on it. It has a cradle that can be used to charge it. When I take it off the cradle, KDE warns that the battery is low, so it shuts itself down.

The suppliers support suse and have provided a suse driver for power management that will shut it down correctly, and bring it out of sleep when the screen is touched.

What are the chances that the Suse driver will work on centos 5? How different are the two distros internally when it gets to low-level stuff like power management?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what that "driver" actually does. If it installs its own kernel module I would say "no". If it uses standard plug&play mechanisms and acpi the "driver" will propably work.